# Dapr fails to proxy the request

Tags: c#, dapr

I'm running dapr 1.10.0 version, it's started using this command:

`dapr run --components-path components --app-port 5067 --app-id auditing-example-app --app-protocol http --dapr-http-port 3500 -- dotnet run`

However when I use the Dapr client to publish my events like this:

`await _client.PublishEventAsync("test", "test", myCommandObject);`

It throws a runtime exception saying:

> failed to proxy request: required metadata dapr-app-id not found

What am I missing?

Comment: If anyone comes across - reverting the Dapr.Client version to 1.9.0 made it work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend ensuring that the Dapr.Client version matches the major & minor version of the Dapr runtime.

You can find this out by running `dapr version`

Assuming you are running Dapr in self-hosted mode, you can upgrade your runtime via these instructions

https://docs.dapr.io/operations/hosting/self-hosted/self-hosted-upgrade/